# Having Lower-Case Page Titles in Mediawiki

Tags: php, mysql, macos, unix, mediawiki

I am building a Mediawiki at [here.](http://www.learnbymac.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

It is going OK, but now I want to have some articles to document things that begin with a lower-case letter such as Unix  commands: "man", "chmod", "ls", "iPod", etc.  I don't want them to show up like Mediawiki tries to make all page titles and article titles begin with an upper-case letter.

Also, I don't want the searches to be case-sensitive.  I want searching for "apple" to find "Apple", etc.

I believe that I've achieved having case-insensitive searches by following the instructions from the [web page.](http://itw3.com/en/Disabling_MediaWiki_case_sensitive_URLs)

I believe that this is good, but I am a little squeamish about what I had to do:

1. Change the Structure of the database table _pages, changing the type of the page title to be VARCHAR(255) and changing the collation sequencing to be a kind of  utf-8 case-insensitive.
2. Adding a global function to globalFunctions.php.
3. Changing the php code in the wiki's skin.

It seems like this should just be a php variable in LocalSettings.php

But this all seems to work.  I mean, I could enter "apple" and it would find the article on "Apple" rather than prompting me to create a new article called "apple".

But then, I noticed that the page titles were still capitalized for such things as new article such as an article on "chmod".

I went back to googling and I found a web page that said to use the Mediawiki global variable called:

`$wgAllowDisplayTitle = true;`

and that this would enbled me to use templates such as the following:

`{{DISPLAYTITLE:chmod}}`

http://www.learnbymac.com/wiki/index.php?title=Chmod

This partially works.  The title of the article is now "chmod", but really, in the database the title is still "Chmod" which wouldn't be so bad, but when I go to the Category "Unix", all of the Unix commands show up starting with an upper-case letter.

I read on the Mediawiki site that beginning a page title with a lower-case letter, in any language, is disallowed.

I would like things on my wiki to be like they are on my Mac, not case-sensitive, but case-preserving.

I know that Mediawiki has to consider about every language in the world, but I don't.

I really would rather not modify the structure of my Mediawiki database any further, but maybe that's what's required.  I just noticed that not only are the page titles wrong in the category pages, but they are also wrong in the title when you are editing pages.

[Here's](http://www.learnbymac.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category%3aUnix&action=edit&redlink=1) a link to a category that lists the titles in the wrong case:

---Edit---

I figured it out.  I believe that it is fine now.  I was missing the following line in my Mediawiki configuration file, called "LocalSettings.php:.

```
# disable first-letter capitalization of page names
$wgCapitalLinks = false;
```

I know that I entered this the first time.  I believe what happened was the changes got saved in my local file system instead of being saved by my text editor, via ftp, to my website.

Comment: you just need to use `strtolower()` in the index page template but that would mean you will have all your pages in lower case. best to modify so that it saves to the database in lower-case and remove any Modification made in the template page

Comment: No, strtolower() wouldn't work for me.  I don't want all pages to have a lower-case title, just some of them.  I agree that I would want the data saved correctly in the database.  I managed to do it by setting a Mediawiki global variable.  (See my answer to my own question above.)

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, setting `$wgCapitalLinks = false;` in LocalSettings.php will do the trick. If you already had pages in your wiki, you will probably want to run the maintainence script CleanupCaps as well: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CleanupCaps.php

For your second question: To have the search case insensitive you can use the TitleKey extension (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TitleKey).
It is stable, and used on many major wikis. There is also the possibility to plug in a the Lucene serach engine, if you want more control over the behaviour (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MWSearch)

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I did set $wgCapitalLinks = false;  This helped some, but now, when I click on a word that I want to be capitalized, that doesn't have a wiki page, the page name is not capitalized.  What I really want to do is be able to click on a link and be able to enter the name of the page.  Defaulting to being capitalized would be good, but for exceptions such as "iPod", "iPad", Unix command names such as "chmod", I want to be able to specify the name of the page.

Comment: Ask for the second part of the question, thank you again for your answer.  I think that I will undo the hack from the following link: http://itw3.com/en/Disabling_MediaWiki_case_sensitive_URLs and use the TitleKey extension that you have recommended.  I'll look at Lucene too.

Comment: If you want to change the behaviour on a per page basis, there is a magic word for that: DISPLAYTITLE


To make an exception for e.g. “iPod”, add {{DISPLAYTITLE:iPod}} to that page.

Comment: +1 for {{DISPLAYTITLE:iPod}}.  That's much easier that the hacks that I've done so far, and it does much of what I was looking for.